# How can name value paired XML entries be accessed directly?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a vendor provided XML file that I need to modify programmatically.  The items (nodes, elements, attributes) are several levels deep and have multiple name value paired entries.

```
<root>
  <VendorEntries>
     <VendorEntry Name="Entry1">
        <Attributes>
           <Attribute Name="A" Value="abc"/>
           <Attribute Name="B" Value="xyz"/>
        </Attributes>
     </VendorEntry>
     <VendorEntry Name="Entry2">
        <Attributes>
           <Attribute Name="A" Value="lmn"/>
           <Attribute Name="B" Value="qrs"/>
        </Attributes>
     </VendorEntry>
  </VendorItems>
</root>
```

When looping through the following (in the VS2015 debugger), I see each of the ChildNodes, but don't see how to gain access to Entry1/A so it can be updated from "abc" to "efg"...

```
XmlDocument vendorXML = new XmlDocument();
vendorXML.Load(@"C:\path\file.xml");
XmlNodeList entries= vendorXML.SelectNodes("/root/VendorEntries/VendorEntry");

foreach (XmlNode entry in entries) {  //  /root/VendorEntries/VendorEntry(s) nodes
    XmlAttribute entryName = entry.Attributes["Name"];
    Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Name} {entryName.Value}");  // VendorEntry
    foreach (XmlNode atNodes in entry.ChildNodes) { // /root/VendorEntries/VendorEntry/Attributes(s) nodes
        foreach (XmlNode atNode in atNodes.ChildNodes)  { // /root/VendorEntries/VendorEntry/Attributes/Attribute(s) nodes
            XmlAttribute atName = atNode.Attributes["Name"];
            XmlAttribute atValue = atNode.Attributes["Value"];
            Console.WriteLine($"..{atNode.Name}  {atName.Value} {atValue.Value}"); // ..Attribute Name Value>
            if (entryName.Value.Equals("SOME_ENTRY") &&  atName.Value.Equals("SOME_PARAM"))
            {
                atValue.Value = "NEW PARAM ENTRY";
            }
        }
    }
}
vendorXML.Save(@"C:\path\file.xml");
```

Modified: (Thanks to elgonzo) the code works now.
However, I still don't see a way to directly access the specific attribute to modify without looping through all of the ones that don't need modification.  Does someone have a way to do this?

Comment: `XmlNode` objects have an `Attributes` property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) that contains a collection of `XmlAttribute` objects which represent the XML attributes of this xml node. You can use this to find and modify the XML attribute(s) you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XDocument, you can use Linq to XML to select specifically what you want to modify:

```
var vendorXml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\path\file.xml");            

vendorXml.Descendants("VendorEntry")
    .Where(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "Entry1")
    .Descendants("Attribute")
    .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "A")
    .SetAttributeValue("Value", "efg");
```

Or, as @Prany suggested, you can select the element using XPath:

```
vendorXml        
.XPathSelectElement("//VendorEntry[@Name='Entry1']/Attributes/Attribute[@Name='A']")
.SetAttributeValue("Value", "efg");
```

Or if for some reason you want to use `XmlDocument`, you can use the same approach with that:

```
XmlDocument vendorXml = new XmlDocument();
vendorXml.Load(@"c:\path\file.xml");
var node = (XmlElement)vendorXml.SelectSingleNode("//VendorEntry[@Name='Entry1']/Attributes/Attribute[@Name='A']");
node.SetAttribute("Value", "efg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XpathSelectElement`

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
string value = doc.XPathSelectElement("//VendorEntries/VendorEntry[1]/Attributes/Attribute[1]").LastAttribute.Value;
//This will select value from Entry1/A
```

Comment: What if the position of each Entry & Attribute isn't known by index ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

I like using Xml Linq and putting results in a nested dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, XElement>> dict = doc.Descendants("VendorEntry")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("Name"), y => y.Descendants("Attribute")
                    .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("Name"), b => b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            Dictionary<string, XElement> entry2 = dict["Entry2"];

            entry2["B"].SetAttributeValue("Value", "xyz");

            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If an attribute were then changed, how would that be saved back to the xml file?

Comment: I changed code to make the second dictionary an XElement.  Then added code to change and save value.